# How to get jQuery to hide a div on mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some jQuery code that loads a div with few elements on toggle but I notice that when I scroll the div stays loaded so how do I hide the div on scroll is my question.

This is a part of the code - the way it looks normally is like:

[how it looks normally when loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bxEC.png)

The problem:

[notice that it moves down when scrolled and I want to prevent that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxcCX.png)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // $(".navbar").hide(); //well this works the same for loading pages
    $("#loadindex").load("codeParts/headerDreiHome.html") // loads the second main header part for the navbar
    $("#loadindex").hide();
    $("#loadindex1").load("codeParts/headerDreiHtmlCss.html") // loads the second main header part for the navbar
    $("#loadindex1").hide();
    $("#loadindex2").load("codeParts/headerDreiJava.html") // loads the second main header part for the navbar
    $("#loadindex2").hide();
    $("#loadindex3").load("codeParts/headerDreiJavaScript.html") // loads the second main header part for the navbar
    $("#loadindex3").hide();
    $("#loadindex4").load("codeParts/headerDreiAboutMe.html") // loads the second main header part for the navbar
    $("#loadindex4").hide();
    $("#loadindex5").load("codeParts/headerDreiContactMe.html") // loads the second main header part for the navbar
    $("#loadindex5").hide();
    $("#toggleHome").click(function () {
        $("#loadindex1").hide();
        $("#loadindex2").hide();
        $("#loadindex3").hide();
        $("#loadindex4").hide();
        $("#loadindex5").hide();
        $("#loadindex").toggle("slow", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#loadindex").hide();
            }, 8000);
        });
    });
    $("#toggleHtmlCss").click(function () {
        $("#loadindex").hide();
        $("#loadindex2").hide();
        $("#loadindex3").hide();
        $("#loadindex4").hide();
        $("#loadindex5").hide();
        $("#loadindex1").toggle("slow", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#loadindex1").hide();
            }, 8000);
        });
    });
    $("#toggleJava").click(function () {
        $("#loadindex1").hide();
        $("#loadindex").hide();
        $("#loadindex3").hide();
        $("#loadindex4").hide();
        $("#loadindex5").hide();
        $("#loadindex2").toggle("slow", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#loadindex2").hide();
            }, 8000);
        });
    });
    $("#toggleJavaScript").click(function () {
        $("#loadindex1").hide();
        $("#loadindex2").hide();
        $("#loadindex").hide();
        $("#loadindex4").hide();
        $("#loadindex5").hide();
        $("#loadindex3").toggle("slow", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#loadindex3").hide();
            }, 8000);
        });
    });
    $("#toggleAboutMe").click(function () {
        $("#loadindex1").hide();
        $("#loadindex2").hide();
        $("#loadindex").hide();
        $("#loadindex3").hide();
        $("#loadindex5").hide();
        $("#loadindex4").toggle("slow", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#loadindex4").hide();
            }, 8000);
        });
    });
    $("#toggleContactMe").click(function () {
        $("#loadindex1").hide();
        $("#loadindex2").hide();
        $("#loadindex3").hide();
        $("#loadindex4").hide();
        $("#loadindex").hide();
        $("#loadindex5").toggle("slow", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#loadindex5").hide();
            }, 8000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.divTo').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('.divTo').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="divTo">
    Content
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast response but i solved it as well $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                $('.hideScroll').hide(0);
            } else {
                $('#respnsiveIntro').show(1000);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#respnsiveIntro").hide();
                }, 8000);
            }
        });